# How can I add multiple select option value in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create function that let user can select multiple options in react-select.

Here is my following code for `onChange function`:

```
const [searchUsers, setSearchUsers] = useState(false);
const [searchTeams, setSearchTeams] = useState(false);
const [searchOrganizations, setSearchOrganizations] = useState(false);

  const find = (value) => {
    value.forEach((option) => {
      if (option.value === "Users" && value.length === 1) {
        setSearchUsers(true);
        setSearchTeams(false);
        setSearchOrganizations(false);
      } else if (option.value === "Teams" && value.length === 1) {
        setSearchUsers(false);
        setSearchTeams(true);
        setSearchOrganizations(false);
      } else if (option.value === "Organizations" && value.length === 1) {
        setSearchUsers(false);
        setSearchTeams(false);
        setSearchOrganizations(true);
      } else {
        setSearchUsers(false);
        setSearchTeams(false);
        setSearchOrganizations(false);
      }
    });
  };

  const findList = [
    { value: "Users", label: "Users" },
    { value: "Teams", label: "Teams" },
    { value: "Organizations", label: "Organizations" },
  ];

  const searchData = [];
  findList.forEach((item) =>
    searchData.push({ label: item.label, value: item.value })
  );
```

and here is my Select tag:

```
  <Select
    className="search-select"
    styles={customStyles}
    instanceId="long-value-select"
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={animatedComponents}
    defaultValue="Select"
    isMulti
    onChange={find}
    options={searchData}
    theme={(theme) => ({
      ...theme,
      colors: {
        ...theme.colors,
        neutral50: "#fff",
      },
    })}
  />
```

My onChange function is only getting one option value at a time right now. How can I make it take multiple option value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update state from more than one selected option, you must rewrite you're ***`find`*** function:

```
 const find = (value) => {
    setSearchUsers(value.some((element) => element.value === "Users"));
    setSearchTeams(value.some((element) => element.value === "Teams"));
    setSearchOrganizations(value.some((element) => element.value === "Organizations")
    );
  };
```

**FYI** - [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array
> passes the test implemented by the provided function